# What is the correct translation of "Venetiarum" in this context?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, semantics

This is the whole phrase: Diebus 16. et 17- a Januarii 1797. ad Rivoly, et **Monti Baldo Venetiarum**, phalanx haec duo propugnacula hosti eripuit, in hac pugna 17 viri caesi.

What does Venetiarum mean in this case? Could it be translated as: **Monti Baldo, on the territory of (the Republic of) Venice**?

I really appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Latin name for Venice is *Venetiae, -arum*, f., so *Venetiarum* simply means "of Venice."

The purpose of this addition is probably to distinguish the place from others of the same name; in particular, it could be to avoid confusion with Mombaldone in Piedmont, which is also *Mons Baldo* in Latin.

As for translation, "on the territory of the Republic of Venice" is quite a mouthful. "The Venetian Monte Baldo" would probably suffice.

Comment: We might add that there are plenty of other Latin place-names with a genitive plural suffix, such as *Lutetia Parisiorum*, the muddy place of the tribe *Parisii*.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Indeed, but this is a different construction. Quite a few towns simply have plural names in Latin, the most famous probably being *Athenae* and *Pompeii*.